# Best approach to wait untill all service calls have returned response in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular how i come through that all service calls have returned its response for stopping loading bar in controller

Comment: Please provide some code for your calls and your loading bar.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**.
If you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a 
**clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
 I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. 
Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: `$q.all()`, [Read More](https://toddmotto.com/promises-angular-q)

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solution is to implement a interceptor. An interceptor is a factory that intercepts all request & response triggered from your angular application.

```
app.factory( 'Inteceptor', function($rootScope) {
 int count = 0;
 return {
   request : function() {count++},
   requestError : function() {},
   reponse : function() {
                  count--; 
                  if( count == 0 ) { 
                         $rootScope.$broadcast( 'Event' ) 
                  }
   },
   responseError : function() {}
}});
```

In this interceptor you can keep a count of total request sent. Start from zero, on requeset increment it and on response decrement it. 
And to know when all requests are done, you can simply broadcast an event to let everyone know that all requesets have been fulfilled.

And this is how you push an interceptor in config method.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('CustomHttpInterceptor');
```